# Ruby on rails migration with foriegn key and index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have following migration

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
    t.references :task, null: false, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }
    ...
    t.index :task_id, name: :index_task_id
```

After running migration when I check strucutre I can see two indexes

```
  index_task_id" btree (task_id)
  index_projects_on_task_id" btree (task_id)
```

As I am adding here foreign key, but my reviewer told me to add index, when I check structure I think now it is making two indexes. So why I need another index? will it not make db write slower due to unnecessary index?. I think that is old way when references in migration were not used. But now in references used it automatically create foriegn_key + index.
please correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting two database indices is that the `index` option for [`add_reference`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) (this is the method wrapped by [`references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references)) defaults to true.

If needed you can configure the index by passing the same options that [`add_index`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) takes:

```
t.references :task, null: false, 
                    foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade },
                    index: { name: 'index_task_id' }
```

And you can also suppress the generation of the index by passing `false`.

> I think that is old way when references in migration were not used.

The default was changed in Rails 5.